# JQuery PWI loading never ends

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, picasa

I'm using [JQuery Picasa Webalbum Integrator](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pwi) that gets filled from codebehind. But it's not getting further than the loading screen.

My code so far looks like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%-- JQuery Libary --%>
    <script src="Java/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <%-- SlimBox --%>
    <link   href="Java/jquery.slimbox2/jquery.slimbox2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="Java/jquery.slimbox2/jquery.slimbox2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Java/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <%-- PWI --%>
    <link   href="CSS/pwi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="Java/jquery.pwi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

The Codebehind looks like this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "";

            Literal1.Text = "";
            Literal1.Text += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
            Literal1.Text += "$(document).ready(function() {";
            Literal1.Text += "$(\"#container\").pwi({";
            Literal1.Text += "username: '" + Gallery.GetByID(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"])).Username + "',";
            Literal1.Text += "mode: 'albums',";
            Literal1.Text += "albums: [\"" + Gallery.GetByID(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"])).Album + "\"],";
            Literal1.Text += "thumbCss: { margin: '5px' },";
            Literal1.Text += "onclickThumb: \"\"";
            Literal1.Text += "});";
            Literal1.Text += "});";
            Literal1.Text += "</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "";
            Label1.Text = "Fejl";
        }
    }
```

the Querystring I get from a different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fault. It was the username. You see my picasa account got two emails connected to it, which apparently gives a problem when loading. What I did was to create a new acount and a new album, and now it all works fine. As long as the album is public.